# Common buttons or tabs at bottom for every activity

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I want to put some shortcuts or buttons at bottom of every screen/activity. I understand we can do that by using framelayout/ relativelayout, tab widget etc.

Since, I need it for every activity, do I need to write XML layout for every activity and the button actions again & again? Is it possible to refer a layout and actions on button click etc so that same code redundancy?

Comment: What kind of shortcuts/buttons are we talking about? Normal buttons or do you want tabs in your application?

Comment: I wanted normal buttons and I resolved this. Thanks for your input !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hallo,

You can use the xml tag:

```
<include layout="@layout/commonfooter" />
```

to include whatever you have in your commonfooter.xml layout file in another layout xml.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks !! I used the <include> tag and it worked !! But, on can I write generic onClick methods for these buttons which will be available in all activites? I tried inheriting the common activity defining all the onclick functions but it didn't worked.

Comment: I'm a bit new to this myself, but have had some success.

Comment: This may be a strange way to do it, but you could define a class (ListenerClass.class) and add a static method `static void setListeners( LinearLayout Layout )`. Then, in the onCreate() of your Activites, call `ListenerClass.setListeners( findViewById( commonLayout ) )`

Comment: You can extend the Activity class with your own MyActivity class, and put your common onClick routines to handle your common buttons in that.
Then, instead of your screen-based Activities implementing Activity classes, you implement MyActivity classes which will include your code.
That's the theory, you'll have to set the return values in your onClick routines according to whether they have been handled so that if they are not handled in one class they get passed back.
I'm afraid I can't offer much more than that as I do things by trial and error and have enough problems of my own!

Comment: Well then, Frink's answer blew mine away.. I learned something new today!